# Software-installation error (makefile) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, makefile

I was trying to install geopsy software, but when I ran `sudo make install` the following error occured:

```
cd mseed/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /opt/geopsy-3.3.0/mseed/mseed.pro ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/geopsy-3.3.0/mseed'
[ -d /opt/geopsy-3.3.0/lib ] || mkdir -p /opt/geopsy-3.3.0/lib
cp '/opt/geopsy-3.3.0/lib/libmseed.a' and '/opt/geopsy-3.3.0/lib/libmseed.a' are the same file
make[1]: *** [Makefile:30: install] Error
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/geopsy-3.3.0/mseed'
make: *** [Makefile:152: sub-mseed-install_subtargets-ordered] Error 2
```

before I ran `sudo make install`, I ran `sudo ./configure -prefix /path sudo make -j 2`

Please help me fix this problem. I'm new on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you are talking about http://www.geopsy.org/download/archives/geopsypack-src-3.3.0.tar.gz .

Follow their guide http://www.geopsy.org/wiki/index.php/Installation:Linux .

To get it compiled use commands below:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qtscript5-dev qtdeclarative5-dev \
libqt5svg5-dev g++ gfortran libfftw3-dev liblapack-dev zlib1g-dev

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.geopsy.org/download/archives/geopsypack-src-3.3.0.tar.gz
tar -xf geopsypack-src-3.3.0.tar.gz
cd geopsypack-src-3.3.0
./configure -prefix /opt/geopsy-3.3.0

make -j8
sudo make install
```

Comment: i used make -j 2 because of the total cores that i had.
i've tried those commands but it still error

Answer (score 0):

> **To resolve this issue first try to install the make command.** First and
> the most obvious installation method is to execute the following
> command:

```
sudo apt install make
```

However, yet an another alternative and probably also the solution you want is the installation of the entire development package build-essential which also includes the make command:

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

In case the make command is still not found check whether the make binary executable exists:

```
 ls  /usr/bin/make
/usr/bin/make
```

Check if you can execute the command using a full path:

```
/usr/bin/make --version
GNU Make 4.2.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

Now, ensure the path to the make is a part of your executable shell path:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Now, you may try to reinstall the make command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure make
```

Comment: The make version of mine is same as yours and the shell path is fine. I've tried all of those commands but it still doesn't work